# C# dll beginner - where does it go?

Tags: c#, web-applications, dll

So i've created my first C# Class Library.  I've created my one method.  I've got my dll and have set the reference in my web project and it works locally.

Now I create my war file and deploy it on our webserver.

Is the DLL bundled in the WAR file or do I need to create a directory on the webserver with the DLL in it?

Sorry if this is a basic question, but I can't seem to find an answer.

Thanks!
Leslie

Comment: WARs are for Java. Are you definitely using C#, and does your web server support C#? What web / app server are you using?

Comment: Not sure I understand; WAR files are for JSP technology, not ASP. They are JAR files (Java's rough equivalent to a DLL) used to distribute web applications.

Comment: thanks, we are moving from Java to C# and didn't realize that WAR is specific to java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web project should have a bin folder. You can place your dll there.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a reference to your DLL and also have copied it to your bin folder in your web project you should be fine.